# Methods to combine related records in one row of continuous form, or achieve equivalent functionality?

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

Disclaimer: I work in an industrial environment, so pardon the somewhat atypical references I am about to provide...

I am building my database in MS Access 2010.  My database has a table [Tanks] that is comprised of a TankID field and relevant information about each tank in other fields.  I have another table [Controllers] that is comprised of a ControllerID field, TankID field, and ControllerType field.  In the real world, each tank has exactly two controllers: a Normal Level Controller, and a High Level Controller, thus each record in [Tanks] has exactly two related records in Controllers.  I also have a third table [Adjustments], that will hold an AdjustmentID field and other information about when these controller setpoints are adjusted.  I currently have 84 tanks in my database (thus 168 level controllers).

My initial conceptual goal was for the user to select what tanks to view on a form filled with checkboxes selecting tanks, and then click a button to open a form showing the controllers for each selected tank, plus textboxes so they can enter in the setpoint data.  Ultimately, I know I can just base my continuous form from the [Controllers] table, but then I will have each Tank listed twice from the parent table (once for each controller), which I really want to avoid.  I also could have the user enter adjustments one at a time, but this isn't feasible as they would have to repeat some rather menial process possibly up to 168 times, and expecting them to do that without error is unreasonable.

This may seem like simple OCD, but I am trying to structure the database the same way the users think about the equipment to minimize errors during data-entry, and I think listing the same tank twice may just confuse the users.  The problem is I cannot seem to come up with or find a manageable and user-friendly solution to accomplish this.  The only thing pseudo-set-in-stone is the need to match the flow of the database with the logical flowpath users will have, which is: Select Tanks > Select Controllers for those Tanks > Record adjustments made on those controllers.

I have tried several different approaches, all based on my conceptual idea of having both related [Controllers] records appear in the same row of the [Tanks] record in a continuous form.  I have tried too many options to post code examples, but a brief summary of what I have tried is as follows:

1. Continuous form based on [Tanks], with unbound comboboxes in the same row that use their RowSource properties to select a Normal ControllerID and High ControllerID from Controllers based on TankID in that row.  This failed because Access cant seem to resolve individual rows in the continuous form, as it asked me for the parameter value for TankID even with valid records from Tanks showing in the form.
2. Subforms in Continuous forms.  This sounds like exactly what I want, but I didn't even get a chance to get an error, Access of course tells me "No" as soon as I try and add a subform.
3. Creating a query that contains both controllers for each tank in one record.  This was what I initially tried first, and failed with multiple attempts.  This really deserves its own sub-list of things I have tried, but long story short, it seems either I just don't have the knowledge to develop a query to do this or I am attempting to use a query in a way other than intended, which seems more likely based on the response from Access on these attempts.
4. Clever formatting.  I attempted numerous methods of trying to format my way out of this, but they were all workarounds and don't warrant consideration here.  Needless to say, they all failed anyway.

I have a feeling I am missing a key piece of info that will tell me either my database isn't normalized correctly, or I need to learn this feature that is designed to do what I want, or, worst case scenario, what I want isn't possible due to some legitimate reason based on how Access works.

Comment: I expect this is too broad or opinion-based to be answerable, at least in Stack Overflow terms. I wonder, in any case, whether you'd need a specific UX eye to answer these questions - is there a website for that?

Comment: Re-reading this, some of your text indicates this is a code problem, but the introduction sounds like a UI question. While I am not sure it is an ideal fit for Stack Overflow, I wonder if screenshots of what you think would work might help. I wonder if it is on-topic for _Super User_, given that it may not be a programming question _per se_?

Comment: What is the relationship between [Controllers] and [Adjustments]? Some sample data would help.

Comment: I asked here because I didn't know what exactly was wrong, but wanted to rule out code problems as you suggested.  I was leaning towards my code, or possibly structure based errors, but wasn't sure.  I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong, so short of posting all the code modules I have thus far, I cant really share the code for what I think may be the problem.  In any case, I did some research on SQL language for queries and think I might be on the right track, I will edit my question here if I can narrow down a code issue, or in Super User if it turns out my code is fine.  Thank you all!

Comment: @Andre [Controllers] and [Adjustments] share a one-to-many relationship, where users will make a record in Adjustments each time they make an adjustment to the controller.  I am kind of building this thing from the big picture down, so I haven't populated any sample data that far down yet, still getting from [Tanks] to [Controllers] but will post more info once I get that far and get some data to play around with... Apologies, wish I could provide more...